# Increment counter for nested for loop in Angular

Tags: javascript, angular, angular6

```
<tr *ngFor="let adjustment of adjustments; let i = index">
  <td *ngFor="let blade of adjustment.blades; let j = index">
    <span> Counter = {{ ???? }} </span>
  </td>
</tr>
adjustments= [[blades: [a]], 
              [blades: [a]], 
              [blades: [a,b,c]], 
              [blades: [a,b]]
             ]
```

output:

Counter = 1

Counter = 2

Counter = 3

Counter = 4

Counter = 5

Counter = 6

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please make your questions clear. See [ask].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why don't you flatten the array in code and traverse on top of flattened array.

It would be simpler that way:

```
const arr1 = [0, 1, 2, [3, 4]];
console.log(arr1.flat());
```

**Approach 2**:

You can write 2 functions to get count and object :

```
  getBlade(i,j) {
    return this.adjustments[i].blades[j];
  }

 getCount(i: number, j: number) {
    let len= 0;
    for(let x = 0; x<i; x++) {
      len = len + this.adjustments[x].blades.length;
    } 
    return len + (j+ 1);
  }
```

And then in HTML you can lookup for either object or the count :

```
<tr *ngFor="let adjustment of adjustments; let i = index">
  <td *ngFor="let blade of adjustment.blades; let j = index">
    <span> Counter = {{ getCount(i,j) }} : {{getBlade(i,j)}} , 
    </span>
  </td>
</tr>
```

Comment: this is for navigation and subnavaigation, we have to traverse with page index. so flatten will not work here as it creates duplicates if the array is const arr1 = [0, 1, 1, [1, 2]];

Comment: thanks, based on your explanation I have updated the answer with one more approach. Please check.

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve it using a directive that attaches to the element you wish to count:

```js
@Directive({
  selector: '[appCounter]',
  exportAs: 'appCounter'
})
export class CounterDirective implements AfterViewInit {
  static nextIndex = 0;

  @Input() appCounter: number | string = '';

  index;

  constructor() {
    this.index = CounterDirective.nextIndex++;
  }
  
  ngAfterViewInit(): void {
    if (typeof this.appCounter === 'string') {
      return;
    }
    CounterDirective.nextIndex = this.appCounter;
  }
}
```

Usage in the template:

```html
<ng-container [appCounter]="0">
  <tr *ngFor="let adjustment of adjustments; let i = index">
    <td *ngFor="let blade of adjustment.blades; let j = index">
      <span #counter="appCounter" appCounter> Counter = {{ counter.index }} </span>
    </td>
  </tr>
</ng-container>
```

The `ng-container` is there to reset the counter.

[StackBlitz example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-7g6awq?file=src/app/app.component.html)